# Setting flex/width of columns in rallygrid with columncfgs

Tags: rally

If you specify the columnCfgs for a rallygrid using the string representation, you get some nice built in functionality for different columns - e.g. the FormattedID column has a link to the item when it is rendered.  However, some of the fields have a default flex that makes them way longer than necessary (mostly the name) which makes the grid look a lot different than I want it to.

You can specify the name column as

```
{text: 'Name', dataIndex:'Name', flex: 1},
```

but is there a way to specify flex for columns that you declare using the format:

```
'Name'
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a weirdness with the grid that we'd like to fix before the GA of SDK 2.  In the meantime you can simply do the same thing the grid is doing to build those preconfigured columns:

```
var nameColumnConfig = Rally.ui.grid.FieldColumnFactory.getColumnConfigFromField(
    model.getField('Name'), model);
nameColumnConfig.flex = 1;
```

Then simply pass that into the grid the same as you would the object literal above.